# How do you score an all wild card Canasta?

Tags: scoring, canasta

Today I made my first ALL Wild card Canasta with six 2's and a Joker in Classic Canasta :O)

How much is this worth please?

Also, it was concealed... does that 'Up' the bonus?

Comment: Are you playing classic Canasta or modern/American Canasta?

Comment: Hiya, We are playing Classic here in Surrey in the UK.

Answer (score 2):

In Classic Canasta, a Canasta of only wilds is not a legal/valid meld.

From [the rules](https://www.pagat.com/rummy/canasta.html#classic-melds):

> **Every meld, whether a Canasta or not, must contain at least 2 natural cards**, and it cannot contain more than 3 total wild cards.
>
> Every meld must contain at least two natural cards. The smallest meld, as usual, consists of three cards, which could be three natural cards (such as 8-8-8) or two natural cards and a wild card (such as Q-Q-2).
>
> Melds can grow as large as you wish. A meld of seven or more cards counts as a canasta. No meld can contain more than three wild cards - so a six card meld must include at least three natural cards, and a canasta must contain at least four natural cards. There is no limit on the number of natural cards that can be added to a complete canasta. A wild card added to a pure canasta of course makes it mixed. Once a canasta contains three wild cards, no further wild cards can be added.
>
> **Note that in this version of Canasta, melds consisting entirely of wild cards are not allowed.**

American/Modern Canasta does allow a meld or Canasta of all Wilds; but that is a less common variant than Classic Canasta. In American Canasta, a wild Canasta that contains jokers and 2s, without containing all 4 jokers, is worth 2000 points (in addition to the value of the 2s and jokers in the meld).

[Source](https://www.pagat.com/rummy/canasta.html#american-scoring):

> - a complete twos canasta scores 3000 points (this is a wild canasta made entirely of twos)
> - a complete joker canasta scores 2500 points (this must contain all four jokers, together with three twos)
> - any other complete wild canasta (containing one, two or three jokers) scores 2000 points

Comment: Oh noooooooo!  I was soo pleased with myself but thank you for putting us right.